# Hide parameters of custom UserDetails in authentication object

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I'm trying to prevent users from being able to read parameters of custom UserDetails objects associated with their accounts.

I'm using Spring MVC. I implemented a custom UserDetails object (called User). I can access its parameters in a jsp page by referring to the authentication object, principle. e.g.

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.email" /><br>
```

Everything works. The problem is I want to store some sensitive information in there. Not just a password but other stuff I don't necessarily want users to be able to determine (e.g. database parameters I associate with their users).

For instance, I can actually display the password:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.password" /><br>
```

It is hashed and salted, and I know security is a whole other topic, but the point is - some fields I don't want them to be able to see at all. I know I don't have to show it in the jsp page, but if it's "showable", I'm assuming that means the authentication token is cached on the user's client, and therefore a clever user could get access to that and read off the parameters then try and play around on our site with malformed URLs and what not.

So, is it possible to hide some parameters, not return them in the authentication object, or should I just throw this stuff in a completely separate object?

Comment: The user isn't cached or send to the user it is all server side. JSP (and also JSF) render server side pages and send those to the client. So the user isn't exposed.